# data imported as class "null" - unable to perform statistics, unable to change class

Tags: r

I am having rather lengthy problems concerning my data set and I believe that my trouble trace back to importing the data. I have looked at many other questions and answers as well as as many help sites as I can find, but I can't seem to make anything work. I am attemping to run some TTests on my data and have thus far been unable to do so. I believe the root cause is the data is imported as class NULL. I've tried to include as much information here as I can to show what I am working with and the types of issues I am having (in case the issue is in some other area)

An overview of my data and what i've been doing so far is this:

Example File data (as displayed in R after reading data from .csv file):

```
Part   Q001    Q002   LA003    Q004   SA005       D106
1       5       3     text      99     text        3
2       3             text      2      text        2 
3       2      4                3      text        5
4      99      5      text      2                  2
5       4      2                1      text        3
```

So in my data, the "answers" are 1 through 5. 99 represents a question that was answered N/A. blanks represent unanswered questions. the 'text' questions are long and short answer/comments from a survey. All of them are stored in a large data set over over 150 Participants (Part) and over 300 questions (labled either Q, LA, SA, or D based on question with a 1-5 answer, long answer, short answer, or demographic (also numeric answers 0 thought 6 or so)).

When I import the data, I need to have it disregard any blank or 99 answers so they do not interfere with statistics. I also don't care about the comments, so I filter all of them out.

EDIT: data file looks like:

```
Part,Q001,Q002,LA003,Q004,SA005,D006
1,5,3,text,99,text,3
2,3,,text,2,text,2
etc...
```

I am using the following lines to read the data:

```
data.all <- read.table("data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings = c("","99"))
data <- data.all[, !(colnames(data.all) %in% c("LA003", "SA005")
```

now, when I type

```
class(data$Q001)
```

I get NULL

I need these to be Numeric. I can use summary(data) to get the means and such, but when I try to run ttests, I get errors including NULL.

I tried to turn this column into numerics by using

```
data<-sapply(data,as.numeric)
```

and I tried

```
data[,1]<-as.numeric(as.character(data[,1]))
```

(and with 2 instead of 1, but I don't really understand the sapply syntax, I saw it in several other answers and was trying to make it work)
when I then type

```
class(data$Q001)
```

I get "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

If I do not try to use sapply, and I try to run a ttest, I've created subsets such as

```
data.2<-subset(data, D106 == "2")
data.3<-subset(data, D106 == "3")
```

and I use

```
t.test(data.2$Q001~data.3$Q001, na.rm=TRUE)
```

and I get "invalid type (NULL) for variable 'data.2$Q001'

I tried using the different syntax, trying to see if I can get anything to work, and

```
t.test(data.2$Q001, data.3$Q001, na.rm=TRUE)
```

gives "In is.na(d) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'" and "In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

So, now that I think I've been clear about what I'm trying to do and some of the things I've tried...

How can I import my data so that numbers (specifically any number in a column with a header starting with Q) are accurately read as numbers and do not get a NULL class applied to them? What do I need to do in order to get my data properly imported to run TTests on it? I've used TTests on plenty of data in the past, but it has always been data I recorded manually in excel (and thus had only one column of numbers with no blanks or NAs) and I've never had an issue, and I just do not understand what it is about this data set that I can't get it to work. Any assistance in the right direction is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you really using `sep=","`, and is your data file really not comma-separated?  The syntax above is a little mangled, but from what you showed it appears that you're trying to read space-separated data with a comma separator specified ...  What is the result of `str(data.all)` ...???

Comment: sorry, I separated it by spaces in my example so that it was easier to read. That's how my data looks when type "data" in R. The original file is Part,Q001,Q002,LA003,Q004,SA005,D006. I will edit to make this clear. Getting the data in isn't the issue, the class that is is importing as seems to be the issue...

Comment: We still need to see the output of `str(data.all)` and `str(data)` to be able to get anywhere with this ...

Comment: When I perform `str(data.all)` on my actual large data file I get `'data.frame': 172 obs. of 423 variables: $ ï..Q001 : int 5 4 5 5 5 4 3 5 4 4 ... $ Q002 : int 5 4 3 5 4 5 2 5 4 4 ... $ Q003 : int 5 4 4 5 4 5 3 5 3 4 ... $ Q004 : int 5 4 4 5 4 5 3 5 4 4 ... $ Q005 : int 5 4 4 5 4 5 2 5 4 4 ... $ Q006 : int 5 4 4 5 4 4 2 NA 5 4 ...` When I then ask it to display the data `data.all$Q001` I get `NULL` So it's giving me NULL before I even do ANY further manipulations other than read the data file in.

Comment: Notice that there are a couple of strange characters before the name of the first column: `$ ï..Q001` as above. A couple of questions -- (1) do things work OK for other columns (e.g. `Q002`)? (2) do they work if you use `data[[1]]` rather than `data$Q001`? (3) Can you check if there might be some funny characters in the header of your file?

Comment: Well that is interesting. It looks like `data[[1]]` DOES give the appropriate information, but `data$Q001` returns NULL. `data$Q002` returns data, as does `data[[2]]`. `class(data$Q001)` returns NULL, `class(data$Q002)` returns integer.
In the file there are no strange characters before the first line of information. The top section of my files has "Q001", "Q002" etc then the next line starts 5, 5, 5, so now I'm realy confused as to why Q001 is giving null, but the others are working. I didn't know the data[[1]] method of calling columns, that will definitely be helpful, at the least!

Comment: You can fix this by specifying `names(data)[1] <- "Q001"`, I think. There **are** some weird characters in the header, I think they're just not showing up in whatever way you're inspecting the data.  This is why showing us the results of `str(data.all)` right away would have been useful ...

Comment: That did correctly label the column for me, thanks!
I'd looked at the file in notepad and saw nothing weird in it, i'd never heard of str(data) before so I was confused as to what it really did, I thought it had something to do with the question you'd asked about the comma separater or I would have answered your first comment with that, sorry! I've never done anything more complex with R than read a tab delimited file with headers and then run basic t.test/anova/summary with it, so I don't really know the more complex items I need to work with the current data set... leading to these problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
> z <- read.table(textConnection("Part,Q001,Q002,LA003,Q004,SA005,D006
+ 1,5,3,text,99,text,3
+ 2,3,,text,2,text,2
+ "),header=TRUE,sep=",",na.strings=c("","99"))
> str(z)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Part : int  1 2
 $ Q001 : int  5 3
 $ Q002 : int  3 NA
 $ LA003: Factor w/ 1 level "text": 1 1
 $ Q004 : int  NA 2
 $ SA005: Factor w/ 1 level "text": 1 1
 $ D006 : int  3 2
> z2 <- z[,!(colnames(z) %in% c("LA003","SA005"))]
> str(z2)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Part: int  1 2
 $ Q001: int  5 3
 $ Q002: int  3 NA
 $ Q004: int  NA 2
 $ D006: int  3 2
> z2$Q001
[1] 5 3
> class(z2$Q001)
[1] "integer"
```

The only I can think of is that your second command (which was missing some terminating parentheses and brackets) didn't work at all, you missed seeing the error message, and you are referring to some previously defined `data` object that doesn't have the same columns defined.  For example, `class(z$QQQ)` is `NULL` following the above example.

**edit**: it appears that the original problem was some weird/garbage characters in the header that messed up the name of the first column.  Manually renaming the column (`names(data)[1] <- "Q001"`) seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Your code gives me `z$Q001 > logical(0)` However, my code directly after read in gives `data.all$Q001 > NULL` My code is the same other than that I am reading from the text file data.csv rather than using textConnection. I didn't run my second line of code to filter LA/SA columns and the Q columns still give NULL

Comment: This solved the problem for that column, but unfortunately in my large data set at least half of the columns have imported in as NULL. So, while renaming the column seems to work, this now has to be done for over 200 columns of data... approximately half of my data imported as Null using the `class(data$Q001)` format, whereas all are appropriate when using `class(data[[1]])`. So the solution works to fix each column one by one but does not solve the original problem of why these columns are assigned as NULL in the first place. Column 1 imported with garbage characters...

Comment: but `str()` will not display my full list (truncates after 100), so I cannot see if those somehow have random characters in front. The only connection I have is that the columns after a text answer column have become null (though that doesn't explain why the first column would have that issue), but I haven't been able to check every single line as there are over 500 of them. Thus, while it seems the values are correct and registering as integers, i can't know why these columns were assigned as NULL in the first place, and while the fix works to reassign the names, it fixes, it doesn't solve.

Comment: If you really want all the columns renamed you can just do `names(data) <- paste("Q",1:999)` (getting the leading zeros is a little more work -- see `?sprintf` and possibly ask for more help in a separate question).  If you just want to see all the names (to find out which ones are messed up) do `names(data)`

Comment: Can you post your original data file somewhere?